# Extracting data from a DataRow using a DataSet

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, dataset

Example 1 throws an exception when the price is a null value, Example 2 shows a null value. How do these two ways of extracting data from a DataRow differ?

```
Using ta As New DataSet1TableAdapters.titlesTableAdapter
        Dim table As New DataSet1.titlesDataTable
        Dim row As DataSet1.titlesRow

        table = ta.GetData

        For Each row In table

            'Example 1
            'Throws an exception with nulls
            Response.Write(row.price & "<br>")

            'Example 2
            'Displays Nulls
            Response.Write(row("price") & "<br>")

        Next
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

When you concatenate a null with a string you get null. Best to do something like

```
Using ta As New DataSet1TableAdapters.titlesTableAdapter
    Dim table As New DataSet1.titlesDataTable
    Dim row As DataSet1.titlesRow

    table = ta.GetData

    For Each row In table

        if (row("price") is Nothing) Then
            Response.Write(row("price") & "<br>")
        else
            Response.Write( "<br>")
        End If
    Next
End Using
```

Or some shorter hand version of that. I'm guessing that the first example produces an exception because it is implicitly calling ToString() on row.price and since that is null, it is giving an exception.